# date functions in R return wrong year

Tags: r, strptime

I am trying to convert a character field into a date field for which the options are to either use `strptime` function or `as.Date` function. Here is two reproducible examples:

```
strptime(c("5/13/2015"),"%m/%d/%y")
#result is  "2020-05-13 MST"

as.Date(c("5/13/2015"), format = "%m/%d/%y")
#result is "2020-05-13"
```

Why did the functions change the year from 2015 to 2020?  If instead, I format my date string and use the as.Date function it works. Here is what I did:

```
as.Date(c("2015/5/13"))
```

and it works fine.

any thoughts?

Comment: As an aside note that you don't need `c(...)` as `c("5/13/2015")` is identical to `"5/13/2015"`.  Also since these are dates with no times it is better to use `Date` class.

Comment: Two digit years format is `"%y"`, **four** digits years is `"%Y"`. Upper case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend `lubridate` for date conversions

```
library(lubridate)

mdy("5/13/2015")

# [1] "2015-05-13"
```

Answer (score 6):

Your date format string should use a capital "Y", which captures the full date with century, such as "2015". Lowercase "y" is used to capture the year in two digits, as when "2015" is written in shorthand as "15". In your original cases, the `strptime` and `as.Date` functions incorrectly interpret the "20" in "2015" as the 2-digit year. The corrected version:

```
strptime(c("5/13/2015"),"%m/%d/%Y")

"2015-05-13 EDT"
```